# Regarding the correct usage of `function`

Tags: function, python-2.7

The following block of code does not seem to run properly (more specifically, it doesn't print out the string) and I'm wondering what's causing the error.

I'm assuming it has something to do with my way of calling the function on the last line, perhaps? I'd like to `return` the value `980` to the function `hotel_cost(nights)` so that `print hotel_cost(nights)` prints out `980`.

---

```
def hotel_cost(nights):

    """ Calculate the total staying cost,
    based on how many days you're looking to stay. $140 per night. """

    total = 140 * nights

    print "The total cost of staying %s nights is: %s" % (nights, total)

    return hotel_cost(7)
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to create the function that returns the total cost of the hotel.

Then you call the function from outside.  You do not normally call the name of a function from inside it (called recursion, and a more advanced technique.)

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    """ Calculate the total staying cost,
    based on how many days you're looking to stay. $140 per night. """

    return 140 * nights

# Outside the function
nights = 7
total = hotel_cost(nights)
print "The total cost of staying %s nights is: %s" % (nights, total)
```